# Mac OSX Terminal different colors

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, colors, prompt

Is there a way for the command line and the output to be in different colors? For example, I've been playing with the PS1 value so my prompt is in red, but I'd like to have the command line in green and the output in white (ex: if I type "ls", that's in green, and then the file list is in white).

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/613460/bash-color-prompt-and-command-differently-from-output-stream?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

At the end of your PS1 have an escape sequence set the color of your input. For example,

```
PS1="\h \w$ \e[0;32m"
```

(all that matters is the `\e[0;32m` part at the end (which could be any color), the rest is up to you)

To set the output color differently, you need to "trap" the "DEBUG" signal and call some function. Here's what I have

```
debug()
{
  echo -n $'\e[0m';
}
trap debug DEBUG
```

It's not complicated, it just ensures that whenever you enter a command (which causes the DEBUG signal) the `debug` function is called.

So just copy those lines into your .bash_profile or .bashrc or whatever you're using, and change the '\e[0m' to whatever color you like.

Comment: The `PS1="\h \w$ \e[0;32m"` line causes problems with line wrapping in OS X. Surround ANSI escapes with `\[` and `\]` to solve. In other words: `PS1="\h \w$ \[\e[0;32m\]"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the shell, or a program, emit the appropriate escape sequence to change the colours after you press enter.

The bash shell used by current OS X doesn't have an obvious facility for doing this.

Comment: Is there any way to alias a return key to be "color escape sequence + return"?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind another key to send the escape sequence and a return.

1. In Terminal's preferences, click on the Settings pane, then the Keyboard tab.
2. Click the plus button.
3. Choose a modifier and key. Set the action to `send string to shell` and the string to `\033[m\015`. Click OK.

You'll have to get used to using that keyboard shortcut instead of <kbd>return</kbd>…although there's probably an app that will let you the system treat <kbd>return</kbd> in Terminal as that alternate shortcut.