# Bash: color prompt and command differently from output stream

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, colors

I'd like to color the prompt and command of my shell differently from the text printed in the output stream.

My current export for `PS1` is as follows:

```
export PS1="\e[0;36m\h:\e[m \e[1;33m\w\e[m\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\e[0;37m➜\e[m "
```

I'm coloring the first line of the multi-line prompt correctly, but in the second line I'd like to color both the prompt arrow `➜` and the command itself white, while preserving the output as gray.

For example, see the following screenshot of my shell. I'm attempting to color the command `ls` white in addition to the prompt arrow `➜`, but nothing else. I haven't been able to figure out how to color the command without changing the text color setting for the entire Terminal theme.

[image: Screenshot of shell output]

Comment: You might get some hints from http://superuser.com/q/610058/195224

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/726181/coloured-commands-in-terminal-prompt - this person also wants to change their input line color, not just the PS1 (but not their output).

Answer (score 3):

[Different colors for text entry and console output](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Different_colors_for_text_entry_and_console_output) explains how to do it:

```
export PS1="\e[0;36m\h:\e[m \e[1;33m\w\e[m\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\e[0;37m➜ "
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m" ' DEBUG
```

Should do what you want:

[image]