# Coloured commands in terminal prompt

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I've customized the prompt in my Mac terminal like this:

```
export PS1="\[\e[31;1m\] \w $ \[\e[0m\] "
```

This way I get the `/working/directory $` in bold red, but I also want to get the command I execute in bold red. Nonetheless, I want the output of the command to be of default color.

Basically I want this:

[image]

Any help, please?

---

EDIT: I tried the code on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/204014/214783) but at least for me it is not working. It makes the command bold, but also the command output. And in fact I'm getting an extra ${OFF} tag printed after the command output and even a crazy behaviour when I press up key to see previous executed commands...

Comment: Alright, I'm reopening the question and cleaning this comment thread up. Please add a reference to [the question I linked](http://superuser.com/questions/204003) to the question and state that it doesn't work (and explain in detail what *does* happen when you try it). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

```
export PS1="\[\e[31;1m\] \w $ "   
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m" ' DEBUG
```

All the magic comes from [Escapes between command input and output](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Escapes_between_command_input_and_output)
.

Comment: If anyone has compatibility issues with this, try `trap "printf '\033[0m'" DEBUG` instead.

Comment: On MacOS High Sierra, the ```printf``` method works, where the ```echo``` method does not.  Additionally, it doesn't matter if I use ```\e``` or ```\033``` - they both apparently evaluate to the escape character.  I also tried swapping the single and double quotes, which also made no difference.